# Not equal to != and !== in PHP

Tags: php, operators

I've always done this: `if ($foo !== $bar)`

But I realized that `if ($foo != $bar)` is correct too.

Double `=` still works and has always worked for me, but whenever I search PHP operators I find no information on double `=`, so I assume I've always have done this wrong, but it works anyway. Should I change all my `!==` to `!=` just for the sake of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do the PHP equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp)

Answer (score 171, accepted):

`==` and `!=` do not take into account the data type of the variables you compare. So these would all return true:

```
'0'   == 0
false == 0
NULL  == false
```

`===` and `!==` **do** take into account the data type. That means comparing a string to a boolean will **never** be true because they're of different types for example. These will all return false:

```
'0'   === 0
false === 0
NULL  === false
```

You should compare data types for functions that return values that could possibly be of ambiguous truthy/falsy value. A well-known example is `strpos()`:

```
// This returns 0 because F exists as the first character, but as my above example,
// 0 could mean false, so using == or != would return an incorrect result
var_dump(strpos('Foo', 'F') != false);  // bool(false)
var_dump(strpos('Foo', 'F') !== false); // bool(true), it exists so false isn't returned
```

Answer (score 43):

!== should match the value and data type

!= just match the value ignoring the data type

```
$num = '1';
$num2 = 1;

$num == $num2; // returns true    
$num === $num2; // returns false because $num is a string and $num2 is an integer
```

Answer (score 5):

`$a !== $b` **TRUE** if `$a` is not equal to `$b`, or they are not of the same type

Please Refer to [`http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the info here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

It's scarce because it wasn't added until PHP4.  What you have is fine though, if you know there may be a type difference then it's a much better comparison, since it's testing value *and* type in the comparison, not just value.