# What's the difference between equal and identical comparison operators in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do the equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-compariso)

I know the basic difference between `==` and `===` , but can some experienced coders tell me some practical examples for both cases?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641819/php-not-equal-to-and/3641837#3641837 (compares `!=` and `!==` but you get the idea)

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php gives a great overview!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`==` checks if the values of the two operands are equal or not. `===` checks the values as well as the type of the two operands.

```
if("1" == 1)
   echo "true";
else
   echo "false";
```

The above would output `true`.

```
if("1" === 1)
   echo "true";
else
   echo "false";
```

The above would output `false`.

```
if("1" === (string)1)
   echo "true";
else
   echo "false";
```

The above would output `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to display it is with using strings. Two examples:

```
echo ("007" === "7" ? "EQUAL!" : "not equal"); 
echo ("007" == "7" ? "EQUAL!" : "not equal");
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @DavidT.'s example, a more practical example is the following:

```
$foo = "Goo";
$bar = "Good Morning";
if (strpos($bar,$foo))
  echo "Won't be seen, returns false because the result is in fact 0";
if (strpos($bar,$foo) !== false)
  echo "True, though 0 is returned it IS NOT false)";
```