# PHP While loop with rand() and if statement for rand

Tags: php

this is my first post.
I am sorry for the totally amateur question but I want to learn PHP so I started doing some online courses-tutorials for PHP and there was an example without explanation and I can't find the answer on google.

In the code line 4 $flip = rand(0,1); that means that $flip is getting a random number 0 or 1 right?
Then at line 6 there is if ($flip) { ...
But they don't explain what "if ($flip)" means or equals to. 
For example $flip = 1 or $flip = 0. Thank you in advance.

```
$headCount = 0;
$flipCount = 0;
while ($headCount < 3) {
    $flip = rand(0,1);
    $flipCount ++;
    if ($flip){
        $headCount ++;
        echo "<div class=\"coin\">H</div>";
    }
    else {
        $headCount = 0;
        echo "<div class=\"coin\">T</div>";
    }
}
echo "<p>It took {$flipCount} flips!</p>";
```

Comment: it like TRUE or FALSE. generally 1 Means TRUE and 0 means FALSE in conditional statement

Comment: `if ($flip)` is in this code equal to `if ($flip != 0)`. See [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) for boolean conversions.

Comment: if randomized to 0 the this is false else its a true

Comment: You can use 1 and 0 for boolean values. Look in http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Comment: @Random OK, you're right, bus as I wrote - in this code, where `$flip` only equals 0 or 1. But right, I'll edit my comment.

Comment: in short, for future readers: `if($flip)` is the short form of `if($flip==true)`, which could also be written as `if ($flip == 1)`

Comment: Tip : when `$flip=0;` then `if($flip)` will be true. `if($flip===0)` will be `FALSE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in you first assumption:

```
$flip = rand(0,1);
```

`$flip` will be equal to either 0 or 1. The below for example:

```
$flip = rand(0,5);
```

Will return a number between 0 and 5 randomly.

Generally if you do an `if` statement like so

```
if($example)
```

You are testing if the value is true or false. True can also be expressed as 1 and false can also be expressed as 0.

Therefore as `$flip` is equal to a 0 or 1, it is equal to either true or false. So if flip is true or 1, then it will execute the code in the if statement. As a note you could reverse how the if works by testing for false using:

```
if(!$flip)
```

Effectively if `$flip` is greater than 0 it will be considered true, see the example below:

```
$test = 0;
if($test) //This will be false and therefore echo It is false
{
  echo "It is true";
}
else
{
  echo "It is false";
}

$test2 = 5;
if($test2) //This will be true and therefore echo It is true
{
  echo "It is true";
}
else
{
  echo "It is false";
}
```

**Update**

You could consider the following to effectively be the same:

```
  if($flip)
  if($flip == 1 || $flip == true || $flip > 0)
```

Comment: So to make it clear for me and the other people reading.

Let's say we make $flip = rand(0,9); Flip is getting one of the following 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

So if ($flip) which actually means $flip == 1 and the statement that follows will occur only when $flip == 1 otherwise will go to else

Comment: @Kiri - You are mistaken. It means `if($flip)` checks if `$flip` is  `0` or `FALSE`. The `if` doesnt compare or check if its `1` or `TRUE`.

Comment: @Kiri as kishor mentions, the `if` doesn't care if the value is eith `1` or `true`, just simply that it is not false and not 0. I have put an update above to help clarify.

Comment: This page explains which values are cast to which booleans in detail: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Comment: Technically, the if does care whether it's 1 or true; it will cast whatever result it gets down to a boolean. The reason that both 1 and true will go in the branch is because 1 when cast to a boolean becomes true.

Comment: Yes my mistake I meant 0 but anyway with your comments things are totally clear now. The if($flip) more or less is like the binary 01 true or false, electricity passing or not.

Comment: Dont use two = to compare, always use ===

Comment: @Ara can you explain why?

Comment: @Kiri Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641819/php-not-equal-to-and?lq=1

Comment: @Ara very interesting! Thank you for the info. I also found another post plus I will post 2 examples for people to get it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp

http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_oper_equal

http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_oper_identical

Answer (score 1):

Basically In PHP expression is evaluated to its Boolean value. for e.g

```
if($flip) // means if(1) or if(0)

if (expr)
  statement
```

> 0 : is evaluated as Boolean FALSE

```
if($flip){

} 
else { 
  // goes here
}
```

> 1 : is  evaluated as Boolean  TRUE (non-zero)

```
if($flip){
  // goes here
} 
else { 

}
```

If the value of the first expression is TRUE (non-zero) it enters into if block

Answer (score 0):

A variable equal to 0 means `false`, other numbers mean `true` :

```
if(0) => false // you go in the else statement
if(1) => true
if(2) => true
```

etc...

In fact, when you do `if($flip)`, the test executed by PHP is `if($flip != 0)`

Comment: there aren't a 2 value :)

Comment: @ZakariaWahabi It is for comprehension purpose, since OP wants to learn ;)

Comment: yes i see , but for the comprehension and good comprehension there aren't a 2 value for the booleans , 0 - 1 => false - true thats it :)

Comment: The answer that was totally clear for a starter like me was the one someone post but can't find anymore that if ($flip) actually means $flip==1 or $flip!=0 like Honza Haering said. Thank you all for the answers I can't upvote since my reputation is low.

Comment: @Kiri although your reputation is low you can accept answer you like

Comment: @Kiri Yes i deleted my comment since Honza Haering edited his comment. I edited my answer to contain what  you wish

Comment: Yes I did that already. Your answer is also correct just bit harder to get when you are totally new in PHP.

Comment: You might need to edit your answer @Random. Even though the OP understood what he is looking for, the explanation looks confusing.When would we use such `if` in realworld? and `2` ?

Comment: @Kishor Please exlicit what is confusing ? Then, about your question, first, it would be `if`s with variables (not constant like here), and I had a live exemple yesterday. reading some multi-thread code (with PCNTL). The result of `pcntl_fork()` is `0` if you are in father, and thread's `PID` if you are in the child. So a `if($pid)` is used to check it out... However, it is not recommanded to use it this way, you should explicit `if($pid != 0)` to be clear.

Comment: For a starter, it would confuse him than help him. that was my point. Cheers!