# PHP & HTML in one file

Tags: php, html, css

Okay, so I'm practicing website programming and I have learnt the basics of PHP and HTML. As my first task I decided to try something with medium difficulty, - create a coinflip program. Within my file I have HTML code and PHP code, however when I run this code in the browser, it appears to show the PHP code and not to specifically what I told it to. Whether i've done something wrong I don't know. Please help me point out the errors and where to fix the problem if you know, thanks.

HTML & PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="coinflip.css">
<title>Coinflip | 50/50!</title>

<h1><Coinflip</h1>
<div class="circle">

  <?php
    $flip = 0;
    $winner = rand(0,1)
    if ($winner = 0) {
      echo "<p>The Coin Landed On Tails!</p>"
    }
    else {
      echo "<p>The Coin Landed On Heads!</p>"
    }
  ?>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.h1 {
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}
.cirlce {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px; 
}
```

I have yet to add text inside of the circle etc yet, help would be appreciated.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6nLwL08k/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the file as a `.php` instead of a `.html`. Otherwise, the php is not processed by the server.

Also, as you noted in the comments you do not have a server installed, you will need to install a server that supports PHP. PHP is a server-side language, and is processed by a server program, such as apache. I personally use [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) and have been very happy with it. [Here is an xampp install tutorial](https://blog.udemy.com/xampp-tutorial/)

Install XAMPP, place your files in the `htdocs` folder, then visit `localhost/myfile.php`

Also, as @PVL noted in the comments, you are [missing semi-colons](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php), and have a few more errors in your php:

1. PHP statements must end with a semicolor(`;`), so:

`$winner = rand(0,1)` should be `winner = rand(0,1);`

`echo "<p>The Coin Landed On Tails!</p>"` & `echo "<p>The Coin Landed On Heads!</p>"` should both end with a semi-colon.

2. With `if ($winner = 0) {` you are assigning a value to `$winner`, not checking if the value is 0. Your `else` statement will never be called. To compare the values, use `==` or `===` instead ([Difference between `==` and `===`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641819/php-not-equal-to-and) )
   :

`if ($winner == 0) {`

Your PHP should now look like:

```
  <?php
    $flip = 0;
    $winner = rand(0,1);
    if ($winner == 0) {
      echo "<p>The Coin Landed On Tails!</p>";
    }
    else {
      echo "<p>The Coin Landed On Heads!</p>";
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: So a file saved with a .php extension is just like a .htm/.html except it is used to recognize the php?

Comment: Yes in `.php` file both php and html code interpreted correctly but in `.html` php code will not work

Comment: As @Anant said, yes, a `.php` file will render the same as a html file, except the php in it will have been processed on the server.

Comment: @Anant thanks, do you know how I can run this? It says I need to install a different program.

Comment: I see you forgot semicolons.

Comment: @JacobGray https://gyazo.com/72f6749e55c95a2eed1e6d07f1a4606d this is it, do I need an external program to view it on the browser?

Comment: Do you have wampserver? Install it.

Comment: @JacobGray I installed Xampp, but when I try to active Apache it does not run, and mySQL just shuts down itself

Comment: @MattJones for your project, you don't need mysql, but you probably have a firewall blocking the port or something. I had to add an exception when I installed the first time

Answer (score 0):

You must change the file to a .php and upload to a live server or MAMP or WAMP and run it on a local server that can enable php. HTML is not dynamic so it doesn't need a server to show up.