# Simple PHP comparison doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to check if the user is coming from outside the Netherlands or Belgium by using the following 'code':

```
$countrycode = 'NL'; 

if ($countrycode !== 'NL' || $countrycode !== 'BE') {
echo 'you are not from NL or BE';
} else {
echo 'you are from: ' . $countrycode;
}
```

I cannot figure out why it's echoing the first occurrence.

PS: I know I could just switch it by using `===` instead but I kinda wish to know why or what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Because `$countrycode !== 'NL'` returns false and `$countrycode !== 'BE'` returns true, so `echo 'you are not from NL or BE';` is outputted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php not equal to != and !==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641819/php-not-equal-to-and)

Comment: @WillParky93 thanks! upvoted

Comment: Better to use `if (!in_array($countrycode, ['NL','BE']))` instead - less error prone

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas cool! haven't seen that method before. will use that :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That should be AND not OR.

```
$countrycode = 'NL'; 

if ($countrycode !== 'NL' || $countrycode !== 'BE') { // Since 'NL' !== 'BE' this is true
    echo 'not from NL or BE';
} else {
    echo 'you are from: ' . $countrycode;
}
```

Your first line should be:

```
if ($countrycode !== 'NL' && $countrycode !== 'BE') {
```

Comment: ah yea that makes sense. thanks for your quick response! (I can accept your answer in 3 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

Try the method strcmp(): http://php.net/manual/de/function.strcmp.php
Just keep in mind that it returns an integer instead of boolean. Equality of strings is indicated with a 0 as return value.
Also the comparison is case-sensitive.