# PHP Comparison not working

Tags: php, spam-prevention

I am trying to stop bots posting to a site. We run Googles reCaptcha (v2) and a Honeypot but these are ineffective. I suspect they are using xRumer.

Regardless, until I have Google reCaptcha Beta 3 set up, I wanted to do a simple check to not allow a submission if the email text field contains "@mail.ru" since most submissions are matching this value in the email field.

Simple enough but it's not working. I reviewed this other [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641819/php-not-equal-to-and?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) post but !== also does not work.

It's got to be something simple but I can't see it.

First we check to see if the form is submitted. Then look at the last 8 characters to see if they match "@mail.ru". We also echo the value to confirm the comparison is correct, but it's still allowing the Do Something area.

```
<?php if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")  { 
    // post so do check
    $emailCheck = substr($_POST['email'], -8);
    if ($emailCheck !== '@mail.ru'); {  
?>
```

Do something - only Insert if NOT match on $emailCheck

Close Check

```
<?php } } ?>
```

HTML

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><input name="email" type="text" id="email"></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
    <p>Email Check: <?php echo $emailCheck; ?></p>
</form>
```

Comment: `if ($emailCheck !== '@mail.ru'); {` That semicolon `;` is what's causing your issues. Remove that.

Comment: Qirel, you are 100% correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @Qirel there was an error in the code which was a closing semicolon

```
 if ($emailCheck !== '@mail.ru'); {
```

prior to the opening Brace.

Xrumer still thwarts our attempts to block spam posts but at least this question is accurately answered.