# 'Identical To' Comparison Operator Failing When The Same Data Type And Integer Value Are Matched - PHP

Tags: php, types, integer, comparison-operators

I have a login page that when a user logs in, it starts a session using the id for that user which has been fetched from a mySQL database.

```
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = $db_id;
```

On the user's profile page there is the option to update their personal info. The href for this page uses a GET parameter of the username which is passed into the url

A database fetch is then done on the profile-edit page to make sure that the GET url parameter username returns the user id of the person with that username.

```
isset($_GET['username']) ? $username = $_GET['username'] : header("Location: index.php");

$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username"); 
$stmt->execute([
    ':username' => $username
]); 

if ($stmt->rowCount() !== 0 ) {

    $row = $stmt->fetch();

} else {
    header("Location: index.php");
}

$db_id = htmlspecialchars($row['id']);
```

A check is then made to ensure that the $_SESSION value matches the $db_id value. This is done to prevent someone typing in a different username into the url so they can change that person's details.

```
// EXIT IF NOT LOGGED IN USER
if ($db_id != $_SESSION['logged_in'] ) { header("Location: index.php"); exit; }
```

The final part of the above code works, but when I do `!==` for 'identical to' instead of `!=` for equal to, the code fails?

I've checked both values using `gettype()` with the following:

```
echo gettype($_SESSION['logged_in']);
echo gettype($db_id);
```

Both are returned as 'integer'.

Why does the check fail with `!==` but not with `!=` when they are the same numeric value, and both values are showing as the integer data type?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not equal to != and !== in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641819/not-equal-to-and-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

`htmlspecialchars()` returns a string. When you compare `$db_id != $_SESSION['logged_in']`, `$db_id` is being automatically converted to an int to be compared with `$_SESSION['logged_in']`, which is why the !== comparison is failing.

`gettype()` returns the type of the ***value*** of the $variable, not the type of the variable itself. use `is_int()` and `is_string()` to test for the type of the variable.

Comment: Not sue what this means _gettype() returns the type of the value of the $variable, not the type of the variable itself_   https://3v4l.org/4mLAs

Comment: I think I was distracted by my kids when I wrote that. Looking back at it now, I admit, it doesn't make sense.